# Rails does not properly generate polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run the following command via by using rails 5

```
rails g model Profile name:string:index profileable:references{polymorphic}
```

I got this weird migration

```
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.referencesc :profileable
      t.referencesh :profileable
      t.referencesi :profileable
      t.referencesl :profileable
      t.referencesm :profileable
      t.referenceso :profileable
      t.referencesp :profileable
      t.referencesr :profileable
      t.referencesy :profileable

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :profiles, :name
  end
end
```

env: OSX Sierra 10.12.2, Rails 5.0.1, ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin16]

Comment: are you using yadr?

Comment: can't reproduce working fine for me

Comment: @Denis Not really, I am using prezto and tmux

Comment: try disabling both and/or running a migration through terminal

Comment: @Denis Don't know why but it work now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running `Yadr` or anything else (like in this case Prezto/Tmux) -  try disabling both and/or running a migration through terminal

Answer (score 4):

`{}` is obviously expanded by your shell (brace expansion).

Wrap it in quotes:

```
rails g model Profile name:string:index "profileable:references{polymorphic}"
```

Comment: This may not have answered OP's question, but it certainly answered mine about creating polymorphic relationships from the command line.